# How Do I Use the Excel Function LoadPicture() from a Windows Form Application

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

I have a Windows Form application that my company uses to access all it's reports. Most of the reports are given to the user in an Excel sheet that is created at run-time either from scratch or an Excel Template. This has been working fine for everything up until now. The problem I am running into now is that I need to load an ImageBox on the Excel Template with an image saved on the drive. I have the filepath of the image (this will change each time this run). The only way I have found to be able to set the picture property of the ImageBox is like this...

```
Dim FileStr As String = "C:\Folder\ImageFile.jpg"

xlWorksheet.ImageName.Picture = LoadPicture(FileStr)
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to call the LoadPicture() function from within the windows form. I know I could create an Excel Module at run-time that call the LoadPicture() then delete it, but i just figured there had to be a better way? Hoping someone out there has suggestions. Thanks.
Edit:- Here is an example of the code I am Using to Open The Excel Sheet

```
Imports ExcelVB = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports ad = GartnerInterface.AdminClass.AdminTools
Imports xl = GartnerInterface.AdminClass.XlHelp

Public Class TestClass

    Public Shared Sub NewSub()

        Dim xlApp As ExcelVB.Application
        Dim xlWorkbook As ExcelVB.Workbook
        Dim xlWorksheet As ExcelVB.Worksheet

        Dim TestSht As String

        TestSht = "H:\Josh\ExcelTest.xlsm"

        xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(TestSht)
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        xlApp.Visible = True
        xlWorksheet = xlApp.Sheets("Sheet1")

        Dim FileStr As String = "H:\12117\12117_Original.png"
        'xlWorksheet.RFQImg.Picture = LoadPicture(FileStr)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Just so I understand the problem, you have a VB.NET Windows form app that creates or opens the template .xlsx that contains the code above?  One way, we can open the worksheet and change it programmatically?  I think I did this before and you have to .delete the existing picture (if applicable) then insert another in its place.  [this solution may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247842/file-not-found-comexception-error)

Comment: Not quite but close. my bad. I don't want to have any code in the actual excel workbook if i can help it. I am importing Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to control Excel from within the windows form App.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I'm looking at the code, you would likely need the .AddPicture method

At the bottom of this code, you would need something like the following:

```
Dim FileStr As String = "H:\12117\12117_Original.png"
xlWorksheet.Shapes.AddPicture(FileStr, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 50, 50, 300, 45)
```

Taken from,
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198302.aspx

OR, if you have a template where the image is already named "test"

```
Dim FileStr As String = "H:\12117\12117_Original.png"
Dim imgName as String = "test"
For Each myShape In xlWorksheet.Shapes
    If myShape.Name = imgName then        
       cTop = myShape.ShapeRange.Top 'we must save the values here
       cLeft = myShape.ShapeRange.Left
       cHeight = myShape.ShapeRange.Height
       cWidth = myShape.ShapeRange.Width
       myShape.delete
       Exit For
     end if            
next
xlWorksheet.Shapes.AddPicture(FileStr, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, cLeft, cTop, cWidth, cHeight)
```

[An example, with user interaction, I borrowed from](http://www.excelitems.com/2009/03/change-picture-or-image-location.html)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this

Comment: I have been playing with the add picture to try to get it to work for me but it just can't do what i want. The problem is the pictures can be different sizes. With an ImageBox I can use zoom to make any size image always go in the same spot, and take up the same amount of space, every time. So I really need to know how to load an image into the image box from outside Excel.